# $\mathfrak so(V,B)$ as subalgebra and trace if subsets of it.

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

I'm studying lie algebras, and got stuck on this one:

Let $B$ be a bilinear form on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F$.

I've seen many books that say that  $\mathfrak so(V,B)$ is a lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak gl(V)$, but didn't find a proof.

and also, in the case that B is non-degenerate, how can I show that $tr(X)=0$ for all $X \in \mathfrak so(V,B)$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_orthogonal_Lie_algebra#Lie_algebra

Comment: @Will Jagy I didn't find a proof there

Comment: What book are you looking at? The question varies significantly depending on the field. Over $\mathbb C,$ for example, it is a sequilinear bilinear form that is used, over $\mathbb R$ it is symmetric bilinear. Over the reals with the ordinary dot product, $\mathfrak s \mathfrak o$ is the skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: I managed to solve it myself I think, will check again and upload if seems correct